# How to read only 20 characters from a string and compare to other string?

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison

I am working on hashing. I am hashing a phrase and I can only use 20 characters of the phrase.

How can I read only 20 characters of a string?

How can I compare strings if they are the same?

Comment: "Examples for dummies advised." +1 for your honesty!

Comment: If you are working on hashing, why do you need to truncate your string to 20 chars ? A classical Hash algorithm will produce a result with a fixed size, whatever the source data's length is.

Comment: I don't know who accept! I'm voting you all for very good answers. I must mix and match though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To read 20 chars of a string you can use the substring method. So

```
myString = myString.Substring(0,20);
```

will return the first 20 chars. However, this will throw an exception if you have less than 20 chars. You can make a method like this to give you the first 20, or all the string if it's shorter.

```
string FirstTwenty( string input ){
  return input.Length > 20 ? input.Substring(0,20) : input;
}
```

Then to compare them

```
if(FirstTwenty(myString1).CompareTo(FirstTwenty(myString2)) == 0){
  //first twenty chars are the same for these two strings
}
```

In case of UpperCase then use this Function

```
 if (FirstTwenty(mystring1).Equals(FirstTwenty(myString2), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        //first twenty chars are the same for these two strings
    }
```

Comment: C# has operator overloads too, you should just use `==`

Answer (score 11):

this compares the first 20 characters of string `a` and `b`

```
if (String.Compare(a, 0, b, 0, 20) == 0)
{
    // strings are equal
}
```

for culture specific comparison rules you can use this overload, that accepts a [StringComparison enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx):

```
if (String.Compare(a, 0, b, 0, 20, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
{
    // case insensitive equal
}
```

Comment: Why fiddling around with manually substring if there is built in functionality +1

Comment: +1 Didn't know about this overload either, and it is actually quite useful :)

Comment: [overload accepting StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aaf32ef.aspx) can be used instead, to understate culture-specific comparison overhead

Comment: @abatishchev: right, I added a culture specific comparison example

Answer (score 4):

Compare a string to a string:

```
bool stringsAreEqual = str1 == str2;
```

Read the first 20 chars from a string (the very assured way):

```
string first20chars = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) 
                ? str
                : str.Length >= 20
                      ? str.Substring(0, 20)
                      : str;
```

Comment: Why do you put `?:` on new string, while commonly they're put on the same string? Just curious.

Comment: @abatishchev: what do you mean with *new string*? I just check for null and length < 20

Comment: Hi Jan, I want to ask a question about your code.I am using this kind of expression very frequently in my codes but I generally use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.Why did you use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` but not `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`?Is there a special reason or any differences between these two?

Comment: @Jan: Better to say `new line`.

Comment: @OkayGuy: Most often used is `IsNullOrEmpty()`. The difference is in logic (and name): first checks for null and "", second for null, "", and " ".

Comment: @Jan why are you returning `null` for an empty string?

Comment: @OkayGuy: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` returns true if length > 0 but string contains just whitespace. `IsNullOrEmpty` checks for null or length==0 . In this question i think whitespace is a valid input so i dont want to discard it using `NullOrWhiteSpace`.

Comment: @abatishchev: Ok your question is about code formatting? I think its much more readable when the expression is a bit larger like in this case where two nested ? operators are used.

Comment: @Charlie: ok, i admit that is suboptimal. Have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Substring in C# string Class returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified given index and extended up to the given length.

```
str = "This is substring test";
retString = str.Substring(5, 7); // "is"
```

In your case you must use

```
str.substring(0,20);
```

To compare two strings you use String.Equals()

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = "World";
if(a.Equals(b, true));
```

To ignore the case of the Strings you must use "true".

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = "...";
string first20 = input.Substring(0, 20);

bool eq = String.Equals(first20, anotherString, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

See [String.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx), [String.Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq!

```
if(new string(yourString.Take(20).ToArray()) == otherString.Take(20))
    ....
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned in the comments, to change the IEnumerable back to string. Fixed

You can do this on enumerables only:

```
if(yourString.Take(20).SequenceEqual(other.AsEnumerable())
  ....
```

If you just want to check the beginning of the strings:

```
if(yourString.Take(20).SequenceEqual(other.Take(20))
  ....
```

Comment: You're doing reference equality of an `IEnumerable<char>` and a `string` there. The compiler even warns in that case: *»warning CS0252: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'«*

Comment: I never used Linq for that. But it's far more readable that the construct `return yourString.Length > 20 ? yourString.SubString(0,20): yourstring;`. +1

Comment: That won't work, `IEnumerable.Take` returns another `IEnumerable`, which'll turn that `==` into a reference equality check

Comment: Steve B - The problem is that Take returns IEnumerable<char>, so you will have to convert back to a string again, and that will hurt readability. For example `new string(yourString.Take(20).ToArray())`

Comment: Use [string constructor accepting char array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx): `new String(yourString.Take(20).ToArray())`

Comment: Thanks for feedback, improved examples